# Inkscape: Document Settings Scale and Default Document Settings

Tags: inkscape, vector, scale

Inkscape's default scale of "0.039370" is throwing off measurements when I use the Add-Ruler feature. Is there a way to make the default setting always set to "1.0" when I open any new file?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up all the options in the 'Document Properties' and the rest of the document to how you like it, then use 'File → Save Template...'. It doesn't matter what you put in the dialog for 'Name' or any of the other inputs, just make sure to check the 'Set as default template' box.

Note that not all settings will affect the templates in the 'Welcome' dialog. The scale value for these templates, for example, can't be changed like this.
Inkscape will load the default template when you click the new-button in the toolbar, the 'New Document' button in the bottom-right of the 'Welcome' dialog, or when you open Inkscape with the welcome-screen disabled ('Show this every time' unchecked).