# Where is the white inkscape background?

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape 1.2 settings, I can select a checkerboard background for my document (as before). If I deselect that, it will instead be gray (which is new). How do I get white?

I have tried different themes, but regardless of which team I choose, there is no white background.

(I was trying to add the tag `inkscape-1.2`, but my reputation did not allow that)

[image: settings]

[image: checkedboard background]

[image: gray background]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is the new 'Desk' color.

You can change it with the button visible in your own screenshot:

[image: Desk color selection button]

It seems you might also need to change the 'Page' color with the left button.

Comment: Do I need to do that every time I create a document?

Comment: @AndersLindén These settings and all other options in the 'Document Properties' in general are saved per document. To set them for all new files, [check these instructions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/157969/165916) on how to change the default template.